# acknowledgment size for STOP-AND-WAIT protocol

Tags: efficiency

I looked [**frame size range calculation for stop-and-wait protocol**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/100599/25328) post but I have a similar (?) question.
The question states.
A channel has a transmission speed of 10 kbps. The transmitted frames are sized 550 bit and the propagation is 20 msec. Errors do not exist. Since STOP-AND-WAIT protocol is used how large should the acknowledgment size be in order to have 55% efficiency?

I read that the efficiency type is **efficiency = Tdata/(Tdata + 2*Tprop)** and **Tdata = DataFrameSize/transmission speed**.

Solving that i find that the efficiency is 57%.

So the question asks how the frame size changes in order to have efficiency 55%?

If yes, doing the math that should be 488,88 bits,right?

Am i right or the question asks something entirely different?

Comment: I see no term representing the size of the returned Ack packet in your expression for efficiency. Yet that is exactly what the question is asking for.

Comment: Thats because i couldnt find any expression including the returned ACK packet and the efficiency of the STOP-AND-WAIT protocol. So i assumed that transmitted size and the acknowledgement size is the same. It is something that we should have been taught at class, but we didn't. Is it possible to help me with that and give me the correct expression?

Comment: It's easy if you think about what's happening. Look at your equation and you'll see  the sizes can't possibly be the same. If it's not obvious, draw out a timeline for what happens and when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation assumes a acknowledgment packet with a size of zero and no processing time. The denominator of this equation must be extended to include also:

- the processing time \$T_{proc,R}\$ of the data packet at the receiver
- the [transmission time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_time) \$T_{Ack}\$ of the acknowledgement packet
- the processing time \$T_{proc,S}\$ of the acknowledgement packet at the initial sender.

The time for a complete transfer (request and reply) is:

$$T_{total} = T_{Data} + T_{prop} + T_{proc,R} + T_{Ack} + T_{prop} + T_{proc,S}$$

Putting this into the efficiency equation and then transposing it to the requested acknowledgement packet size is left as an exersize to the reader.